# Tensor product of stable bundle and line bundle is stable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve. Let $E$ be a stable vector bundle (i.e $\mu(F)< \mu(E)$ for all subbundles $F$). Let $L$ be any line bundle.

> $G=E \otimes L$ is stable

I've computed the slope of $G$ to be $\mu(E)+degL$ . To proceed further I'd have to know what a subbundle of tensor product of vector bundles look like.
How can I settle this?

[Here $\mu = deg/rank$]

Comment: Can we say something like this? We have $(E \otimes L) \otimes L^{-1} = E$ so given a subbundle $U \subset (E \otimes L)$ define $U' = U \otimes L^{-1} \subset E$, a sub bundle so by assumption $\mu(U \otimes L^{-1} ) < \mu(E)$ now using your tensor formula gives the result.

Comment: Ahh this twisting back by $L^{-1}$ is exactly what I was missing. Will you be kind enough to type this out as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $(E \otimes L) \otimes L^{-1} \cong E$, because tensor product of vector bundles is associative.

Given a subbundle $U \subset (E \otimes L)$ define $U' = U \otimes L^{-1} \subset (E \otimes L) \otimes L^{-1} \cong  E$, a subbundle so by assumption $\mu(U \otimes L^{-1} ) < \mu(E)$ now using your tensor formula:

$\mu(U) = \mu(U \otimes L^{-1}) + \deg(L) < \mu(E) + \deg(L) = \mu(E \otimes L) .$

That is $E \otimes L$ is stable.

Comment: Shouldn't this argument also hold for higher dimensional varieties ( or atleast for smooth projective surfaces)?

Comment: Sorry I won't have time to think properly about this for a couple of days. It seems that the only thing we use that is specific for dimension is the formula of how $\mu$ changes under tensor. There should also be some formula for this in higher dimensions, then it should be relatively clear whether it is true or not. If I remember correctly this is true for vector bundles over $\mathbb{CP}^2$